# Como converter uma string salva em um arquivo .txt, para um número inteiro?

Tags: python-3.x, string, txt, int

Exemplo:
teste = open('teste.txt', 'w')
teste.write('6000')
teste.close()

Como eu converto o conteúdo do arquivo .txt em inteiro para poder fazer operações com ele? caso não tenha como fazer isso, como eu posso gravar dados sem perder-los quando reiniciar o meu programa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desta forma:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as file:
    data=int(float( file.read().replace('\n', '') ))
```

Quando você usa o `open` com `with` ele já fechará o arquivo. Por isso utilizei desta forma.

Comment: Muito obrigado! :D